# Motive of unlabeled Fulton-Macpherson configuration space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am working on the class of the Fulton-Macpherson compactification of configuration space in the Grothendieck ring of varieties, over the field of complex numbers. As a first step, I am wondering about the case of 2 points, i.e. the motive of $X[2]/S_2$ for a nonsingular variety $X$. For the case the two points coincide, one was lead naturally to the space $(\mathbb{P}(T_x^2/T_x))/S_2\cong\mathbb{P}((\mathbb{A}^n)^2/\mathbb{A}^n)$. My question is: (1) does this space admit an expression in terms of the Lefschetz motive $\mathbb{L}$? (2) does this space admit a cell decomposition? (i.e. is it a disjoint union of locally closed subvarieties isomorphic to affine spaces?)

Comment: I don't understand your notation of $X[2]$ and $P((A^n)^2/A^n)$. Could you clarify ?

Comment: $X[n]$ is the Fulton-Macpherson compactification of configuration spaces of $n$ points.

Also, $\mathbb{P}((\mathbb{A}^n)^2/\mathbb{A}^n)$ is the exceptional divisor of the blowup of $X\times X$ along the diagonal.

Comment: thanks for the explanations. Please add a link to your crosspost on Mathoverflow.